# куда можно загрузить png чтоб CORS не ругался?

Tags: javascript, html5, cors, brainfuck

Если картинка лежит на фейсбуке - я могу ее открыть в canvas, редактировать   и скачать, а если картинка лежит  на том же сервере где и находится мой сайт  (000webhost.com) у меня отображается ошибка:

> Access to Image at 'https://xxx.000webhostapp.com/ava1.png' from
>   origin 'https://xxx.000webhostapp.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```js
function Up() { //загрузка логотипа
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image();
 img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/1387819034852828/picture?width=150&height=150"; 
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 400);
  }
}
```

```js
function download() { //скачиване картинки
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

С facebook работает потому что он вместе с картинкой передает заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"

Соответственно чтобы работало со своего хоста надо настроить вебсервер на выдачу этих заголовков для картинок.

Comment: подскажете как это сделать?) я в тп писал, ни кто не ответил, у меня то домен третьего уровня

Comment: не факт что ваш бесплатный хостинг позволит вам это сделать.

Comment: если только костыль написать, в виде например php скрипта, через который и загружать картинки  и заодно выдавать нужный заголовок через header(); 
но это неправильно :)